# ObservableCoolection RemoveAt

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, mvvm

Проблема в том что DataGrid после удаления из коллекции (ObservableCollection) какого то слова, в DataGrid коллекция остается не измененным. Работает в другом потоке.
Помогите решить эту задачу, в чем может быть проблема? С MVVM работаю не так давно.
Пробовал так:

```
    thr1 = new Thread(() =>{
    for (int i = 0; i <= Word.Count(); i++)
    {

        int rand = rnd.Next(0, Word.Count);
        res = WorkGroup.Start(web, Word[rand].Number);

        lock (_lock)
        {
            //_context.Invoke(() => Word.RemoveAt(rand));

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Word.RemoveAt(rand)));

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Что такое `Word`?

Comment: Эта коллекция ObservableCollection, к которой привязан DataGrid

Comment: Вообщем все работает хорошо, извиняюсь. Сегодня еще раз посмотрел и все удаляется нормально. Можно закрыть вопрос.